# This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7135/ HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I was trying to use controller view and razor pages together. But After Adding the **builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();**
this line in my code when I run the web project shows
**This localhost page can’t be found webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7135/
HTTP ERROR 404**

I tried re-installing the nu get packages. But not working. I am new to .net core 6

Answer (score 0):

I'm reproducing the same issue as you, which is when the default route is not configured:
[image]
When I set up the relevant routes:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

[image]

You can check whether the default route and the page corresponding to the route are configured. If the problem is still not solved, can you share the code of your program to better analyze the problem?